# How to kill feh after calling it with bash?

Tags: raspbian, bash

I have the following code that monitors a directory for any new pictures that are placed into it by a camera. It's not working in it's current state, but the idea is that when it detects a new picture being created in the directory, it displays it in `feh` fullscreened, wait's an amount of time and then kills the process to display the next one.

Currently, it hangs at the step of calling `feh` and doesn't step any further until I manually escape out of `feh`, but then the step to kill feh results in `no feh process found`.

Ideally, I'd love to just be able to refresh `feh` and have it display a new image for every image found, instead of killing it and calling it again but sadly each of the new images has a different file name.

```
#!/bin/bash  
DIR="/path/to/pictures"  
inotifywait -m -r -e create "$DIR" | while read path action file; 

do  
 feh -F $DIR$file 
 sleep 10
 kill -9 ($pidof feh)
done
```

Comment: Add a `&` to `feh ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is, that you need to add a `&` to background `feh`. Otherwise it will wait for `feh` to exit.

This should work, but is maybe not the most elegant solution:

```
#!/bin/bash  
DIR="/path/to/pictures"  
inotifywait -m -r -e create "$DIR" | while read path action file; 

do
  if [ "$pid" != "" ]; then
    kill -9 "$pid"
  fi
  feh -F "$DIR$file" &
  pid="$!"   # $! is a shell variable containing the PID of the last process started
  sleep 10   # You only need this, if you want to show the picture for minimum time
done
```

You actually don't need to get the PID, as this will work as well:

```
do
  pidof feh && pkill feh # this will check if there's a process called feh and kill it
  feh -F "$DIR$file" &
  sleep 10 
done
```

**EDIT:**

You could also use `geeqie` which supports remote control:

```
do
  sleep 10 #only needed for delay
  geeqie -r -t -fs "$path$file"
done
```

Comment: I'm super new to bash. What does declaring `pid="$!"` do?

Comment: `"$!"` is the PID of the last executed program.

Comment: +1 to @jake or the answer (add `&` at the end of the command to background it) but you forgot to add the `sleep 10` delay in the loop that the OP wanted in the question.

Comment: @RogerJones I added it. Thought the `sleep 10` was maybe some workaround.

Comment: Fair enough, although with out it would the script not kill `feh` as soon as it's launched? OP said "...displays it in `feh` fullscreened, wait's an amount of time and then kills the process..."

Comment: @RogerJones In his version it would, not in mine, because it kills the old process only if a new one is started.

Comment: This looks like a kludge on top of a kludge. Hopefully any other users would not see this as viable code.

Comment: @Milliways You're right! Just pointed out the obvious mistakes in the code above. Why don't you let us know how to do it properly?

Comment: @Milliways Like I said I'm super new to bash programming but it's the only way that my current job wanted something done via a RaspPi. This is just cobbled together example code based on previous experience. I'm more than open to other ways to accomplish the same thing.