# Display most recent image in folder on monitor

Tags: display, pi-3b+, image, real-time

I currently have a receiver system that downlinks real-time images of earth from a weather satellite to a Raspberry Pi, where it then stores them as jpgs. What I am looking to do is automatically display the most recent image in this folder, fullscreen on the pi's display, and have this view update as new photos come in (every 30 minutes). Is there an easy way to accomplish this? From what I've been able to gather feh might work, but I'm new to working with Raspberry Pi's and am not too sure what to do next.

Comment: How does your code to download those images look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jake legit answered this same question for me a couple days ago.

[How to kill feh after calling it with bash?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93536/how-to-kill-feh-after-calling-it-with-bash)

Use the `geeqie` code in his edit. It works so much better than `feh`.

**Edit:** I've been told this isn't the most glamorous way to do it though so YMMV